# git pull new updates w/o overwriting existing modifictions?

Tags: git

I have a branch from a master and i have some modified files that I don't want overwritten.  There are changes in master that have been made and I want to get those updates without overwriting my modified files.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is stash your local changes, merge the updates from master, and then apply your stashed changes to the updated branch:

```
$ git stash
$ git merge master
$ git stash pop
```

You could get conflicts when you pop, but that is a risk you have to take to merge changes from another branch.  If that happens you just need to follow the normal merge conflict resolution strategy.

Comment: thx, couldn't I just git pull on master and rebase and deal with conflicts per the rebase?

Comment: Possibly.  It depends on whether or not your current branch has an ancestor in common with master.  Plus, the question was basic enough that I didn't think an advanced answer like rebasing would be a good idea.  No offense intended, but I'd consider rebasing to be something you shouldn't try until you're really comfortable with basic git workflows.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, commit your pending changes so that they are safe. Anything you have committed is basically safe, it will not get lost unless you rewrite the branch with `git reset`.

These are some common strategies to get updates from another branch:

1. You can merge the other branch with `git merge`. This will not "overwrite" your own changes, it will apply the changes of the other branch on top of yours.
2. You can rebase your branch on top of the other branch with `git rebase`. This will basically rewind your branch to the last common revision of your branch and the other, then apply the changes of the other branch, and then apply the changes of your branch on top of that.

Whichever way you choose, there may be conflicts which you will have to resolve. Or you can abort a merge with `git reset --hard`, a rebase with `git rebase --abort`. You should probably read more about these operations in the documentation or the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).